# Compare two buffers for equality

Tags: julia

Is there a way to compare two buffers directly?
For example having two identical files `file1` and `file1-copy`, i would like to do:

```
f1 = open(file1)
f2 = open(file1-copy)
if f1 == f2
     println("Equal content")
end
```

I know i can make strings of that and compare those:

```
if readstring(f1) == readstring(f2)
    println("Equal content")
end
```

Comment: The accepted answer is using Mmap.mmap, since it reduces the the copy operations from disk to memory, which solves the problem described here.

However if the data of your Buffer IS already in the memory anyway, it is smarter to compare just the hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is probably just to [`mmap`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.Mmap.mmap-Tuple%7BAny,Type,Any,Any%7D) them:

```
julia> f1 = open("file")
       f2 = open("file-copy");

julia> Mmap.mmap(f1) == Mmap.mmap(f2)
true
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `Mmap.mmap` and `readstring`? It seems they both use `memcmp` for comparison. I know `Mmap.mmap` is for large files, hard to say which is easier. ;)

Comment: `readstring` copies the entire files into memory and then compares them, which could be expensive if you don't otherwise need it. `mmap` leaves it on the disk but allows you to treat it like an in-memory array.  This also allows it to short-circuit sooner if there are indeed any differences — it needn't read the entire file.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! That makes sense now. I may misunderstand the question: given the readstring example, I thought the author was looking for a method for verifying 2 identical files without explicitly comparing the content.

Comment: My actuall problem is a bit more difficult. I have one file and one PipeBuffer and i want to compare those. I left out this information, since it is almost the same. (well it's not, the data of the PipeBuffer is already in the memory)

Answer (score 1):

I guess not(in the sense that comparing two buffers(`f1`&`f2`) **directly**), but if you could pre-calculate their hashes, it would be convenient to directly compare them later on:

```
julia> using SHA

shell> cat file1
Is there a way to compare two buffers directly? For example having two identical files file1 and file1-copy, i would like to do:

f1 = open(file1)
f2 = open(file1-copy)
if f1 == f2
     println("Equal content")
end

I know i can make strings of that and compare those:

if readstring(f1) == readstring(f2)
    println("Equal content")
end

julia> file1 = open("file1") do f
           sha256(f)
       end |> bytes2hex
"eb179202793cfbfd1a1f19e441e813a8e23012a5bdd81e453daa266fcb74144a"

julia> file1copy = open("file1-copy") do f
           sha256(f)
       end |> bytes2hex
"eb179202793cfbfd1a1f19e441e813a8e23012a5bdd81e453daa266fcb74144a"

julia> file1 == file1copy
true
```